# Encoding issue with Axios

Tags: character-encoding, axios

I am fetching a web page with [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), but the content-type of the response is ISO-8859-1, and the result given by axios seems like it parses it as UTF-8 and the result has corrupt characters.

I tried to convert the result encoding but nothing works, and I think it does not because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3526965)

For example in the [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) library I can set encoding to null and overcome the problem, but I would like to ask you what can I do with axios to disable the auto-encoding or change it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My approach was this:

1. Make the request with `responseType` and `responseEncoding` set as below

```js
const response = await axios.request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.example.com',
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  responseEncoding: 'binary'
});
```

2. Decode `reponse.data` to the desired format

```js
let html = iso88592.decode(response.data.toString('binary'));
```

Note: In my case, I needed to decode it using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-8859-2) package.

Comment: It works very well also if you have to fetch a png and save to disk. You can pass `response.data` to `fs.writeFile()` after setting `responseType` and `responseEncoding` as suggested by @Daniel

Comment: hi, I really thank your help, I solved just for what you write. I am pretty new coding, could you reply these questions?
- I didn't use decode, just => $('.aditem', result.data.toString('binary')).each((i, element) => {
- last posted here, said lating1 too, what's the difference? 
- could you send where to start learning about this? your resource, please
thanks a lot

Comment: Which type is `iso88592`? I get `Cannot find name 'iso88592'.ts(2304)`. You may need `import * as iso88592 from 'iso-8859-2'` from `iso-8859-2` npm package. I see your link at the end, please put it on top of your answer.

Comment: iso88592 is undefined and I have no idea what its meant to be :D

Answer (score 13):

Without using interceptor or another package, I got the response on a buffer with:

```js
notifications = await axios.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: Link,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    reponseEncoding: 'binary'
});
```

And next converting it with:

```js
let html = notifications.data.toString('latin1');
```

Answer (score 5):

In [this github issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/332#issuecomment-222744486) Matt Zabriskie recommends using an [axios response interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors), which I think is the cleanest option.

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    let ctype = response.headers["content-type"];
    if (ctype.includes("charset=ISO-8859-1")) {
        response.data = iconv.decode(response.data, 'ISO-8859-1');
    }
    return response;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const notifications = await axios.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://...your link',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    reponseEncoding: 'binary'
});

const decoder = new TextDecoder('ISO-8859-1');
let html = decoder.decode(notifications.data)
```