# Docusign Document blank after API call

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Im making a call via Request to docusign like so:

```
 var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${baseUrl}/envelopes/${envelopeId}/documents/${documentId}`,
    headers: headers,
    qs: {
        encoding: 'base64'
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
...
})
```

Im getting back the document string but when I write it to a .pdf I get 4 blank pages. Here is the code im using to write it to a file:

```
fs.writeFile('cert.pdf', body, (err) => {
            if(err) throw new Error(err)
        })
```

Nodejs -v 8.11.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040014/how-to-save-pdf-in-proper-encoding-via-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. I'd leave out the `qs: {encoding: 'base64'}` option. The document will be returned as a binary file. (Which is what you want.)
2. When you write the file, specify binary format. On a Linux system, there is no difference. But on Windows there is.

For a code example of retrieving a document, see [this file](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg007EnvelopeGetDoc.js).