# DocuSign API Javascript SDK - getDocument returns string

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am trying to call the api endpoint `getDocument` via Node, and am expecting a Buffer to be returned, however, it is returning a string.  Even when I pass in different values for the `encoding` optional parameter, the data returned is always the same.

When I tested the same endpoint in C#, a MemoryStream is returned which is expected.

My code is as follows:

```
const document = await envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, '1')
```

Where `1` is the documentId (page 1).

The contents of `document` looks like `%PDF-1.5\n%ûüýþ\n%Writing objects...` and so on

I am then trying to save this to a file:

`fs.writeFileSync('test.pdf', Buffer.from(documentContent))`

With no success.  How do I get the api response and save it to a file for viewing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, you will have to use the correct mime type for PDF (in this case) in order to show this file in the browser.

You can find a [node.JS code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/examples/envelopeGetDoc.js) that shows you how to do this.

But the most important part in your case would be this line:

```
mimetype = "application/pdf";
```

Comment: Hi @Inbar, thanks for the quick response.  I'm not quite sure I follow, can you give me an example of how you would pass the mimetype into writeFIleSync, for my example?  Do I need to still do Buffer.from(documentContent)?  It seems like from the code example that documentContent IS the fileBytes.  I am not displaying in a browser, I am trying to save the file to disk.  Thank you!

Comment: see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040014/how-to-save-pdf-in-proper-encoding-via-nodejs

Comment: fs.writeFileSync("testpdf", body,'binary');

Comment: that worked! I initially had tried fs.writeFileSync('test.pdf', Buffer.from(documentContent), 'binary').  The Buffer.from was what threw it off.  Thank you @Inbar!!

Answer (score 0):

fs.writeFileSync("testpdf.pdf", body, "binary")